# Conda has been installing a package for 3+ hours and it doesn't work

Tags: python, conda, miniconda

I use miniconda. After running `conda install -c conda-forge almubentations`, it started resolving conflicts for 3+ hours and then gave me a really long output that didn't fit into the console (a small portion of it at the bottom). But even after that I still can't use the library:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/alexander/dev/python/mynn/mynn.ipynb Cell 3 in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 import albumentations

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'albumentations'
```

Like, it's not even a super complex library, it just performs smome transformations to images. Even Tensorflow took less time to install. Why did this happen and why doesn't it work?

The output:

```
Package mpi4py conflicts for:
tensorflow-base -> h5py[version='>=2.9.0'] -> mpi4py[version='>=3.0']
h5py -> mpi4py[version='>=3.0']

Package libflac conflicts for:
pulseaudio -> libsndfile[version='>=1.0.31,<1.1.0a0'] -> libflac[version='>=1.3.3,<1.4.0a0']
libsndfile -> libflac[version='>=1.3.3,<1.4.0a0']
jack -> libsndfile[version='>=1.0.31,<1.1.0a0'] -> libflac[version='>=1.3.3,<1.4.0a0']

Package libllvm12 conflicts for:
libclang -> libllvm12[version='>=12.0.0,<12.1.0a0|>=12.0.1,<12.1.0a0']
pyside2 -> llvmdev -> libllvm12[version='12.0.0|12.0.0|12.0.1',build='hf817b99_0|hf817b99_0|hf817b99_2|hf817b99_1|hf817b99_1']

Package numpydoc conflicts for:
ipython -> jedi[version='>=0.10,<0.18'] -> numpydoc
jedi -> numpydoc

Package p11-kit conflicts for:
ffmpeg -> gnutls[version='>=3.7.7,<3.8.0a0'] -> p11-kit[version='>=0.23.21,<0.24.0a0|>=0.24.1,<0.25.0a0']
gnutls -> p11-kit[version='>=0.23.21,<0.24.0a0|>=0.24.1,<0.25.0a0']The following specifications were found to be incompatible with your system:

  - feature:/linux-64::__cuda==11.4=0
  - feature:/linux-64::__glibc==2.31=0
  - feature:/linux-64::__linux==5.15.0=0
  - feature:|@/linux-64::__cuda==11.4=0
  - feature:|@/linux-64::__glibc==2.31=0
  - feature:|@/linux-64::__linux==5.15.0=0
  - aiohttp -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - alsa-lib -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.5.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - argon2-cffi -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - argon2-cffi-bindings -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.5.0'] 
  - xorg-libx11 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - xorg-libxau -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - xorg-libxdmcp -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - xorg-libxext -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']

[removed similar lines due to character limit]

  - xorg-libxfixes -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - xorg-libxrender -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - xorg-libxt -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - xorg-renderproto -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - xorg-xextproto -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - xorg-xproto -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - xz -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.5.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - yaml -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.5.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - yarl -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - zeromq -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - zlib -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.5.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - zstd -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']

Your installed version is: 2.31


(tf) [...]$
```

`conda list`:

```
# packages in environment at /home/alexander/miniconda3/envs/tf:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_libgcc_mutex             0.1                 conda_forge    conda-forge
_openmp_mutex             4.5                  2_kmp_llvm    conda-forge
_r-mutex                  1.0.1               anacondar_1    conda-forge
_tflow_select             2.1.0                       gpu    anaconda
absl-py                   0.15.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0    anaconda
aiohttp                   3.8.1            py39h7f8727e_1    anaconda
aiosignal                 1.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0    anaconda
alsa-lib                  1.2.6.1              h7f98852_0    conda-forge
anyio                     3.6.1              pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
aom                       3.4.0                h27087fc_1    conda-forge
argon2-cffi               21.3.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
argon2-cffi-bindings      21.2.0           py39hb9d737c_2    conda-forge
astor                     0.8.1            py39h06a4308_0    anaconda
asttokens                 2.0.8              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
astunparse                1.6.3                      py_0    anaconda
async-timeout             4.0.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0    anaconda
attr                      2.5.1                h166bdaf_1    conda-forge
attrs                     21.4.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0    anaconda
babel                     2.10.3             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
backcall                  0.2.0              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
backports                 1.0                        py_2    conda-forge
backports.functools_lru_cache 1.6.4              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
beautifulsoup4            4.11.1             pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
binutils_impl_linux-64    2.38                 h2a08ee3_1  
blas                      1.0                         mkl    anaconda
bleach                    5.0.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
blinker                   1.4              py39h06a4308_0    anaconda
brotli                    1.0.9                h166bdaf_7    conda-forge
brotli-bin                1.0.9                h166bdaf_7    conda-forge
brotlipy                  0.7.0           py39h27cfd23_1003    anaconda
bwidget                   1.9.14               ha770c72_1    conda-forge
bzip2                     1.0.8                h7f98852_4    conda-forge
c-ares                    1.18.1               h7f8727e_0    anaconda
ca-certificates           2022.6.15            ha878542_0    conda-forge
cachetools                4.2.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0    anaconda
cairo                     1.16.0            ha61ee94_1012    conda-forge
certifi                   2022.6.15        py39hf3d152e_0    conda-forge
cffi                      1.15.0           py39hd667e15_1    anaconda
charset-normalizer        2.0.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0    anaconda
click                     8.0.4            py39h06a4308_0    anaconda
cloudpickle               2.1.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
cryptography              3.4.8            py39hd23ed53_0    anaconda
cudatoolkit               10.1.243             h6bb024c_0    anaconda
cudnn                     7.6.5                cuda10.1_0    anaconda
cupti                     10.1.168                      0    anaconda
curl                      7.83.1               h7bff187_0    conda-forge
cycler                    0.11.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
cytoolz                   0.12.0           py39hb9d737c_0    conda-forge
dask-core                 2022.8.0           pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
dataclasses               0.8                pyh6d0b6a4_7    anaconda
dbus                      1.13.6               h5008d03_3    conda-forge
debugpy                   1.6.3            py39h5a03fae_0    conda-forge
decorator                 5.1.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
defusedxml                0.7.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
entrypoints               0.4                pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
executing                 0.10.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
expat                     2.4.8                h27087fc_0    conda-forge
ffmpeg                    5.1.0           lgpl_he28c0fb_0    conda-forge
fftw                      3.3.10          nompi_ha7695d1_103    conda-forge
flit-core                 3.7.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
font-ttf-dejavu-sans-mono 2.37                 hab24e00_0    conda-forge
font-ttf-inconsolata      3.000                h77eed37_0    conda-forge
font-ttf-source-code-pro  2.038                h77eed37_0    conda-forge
font-ttf-ubuntu           0.83                 hab24e00_0    conda-forge
fontconfig                2.14.0               h8e229c2_0    conda-forge
fonts-conda-ecosystem     1                             0    conda-forge
fonts-conda-forge         1                             0    conda-forge
fonttools                 4.34.4           py39hb9d737c_0    conda-forge
freetype                  2.10.4               hca18f0e_2    conda-forge
fribidi                   1.0.10               h36c2ea0_0    conda-forge
frozenlist                1.2.0            py39h7f8727e_0    anaconda
fsspec                    2022.7.1           pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
future                    0.18.2           py39hf3d152e_5    conda-forge
gast                      0.4.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0    anaconda
gcc_impl_linux-64         11.2.0               h1234567_1  
gettext                   0.19.8.1          h73d1719_1008    conda-forge
gfortran_impl_linux-64    11.2.0               h1234567_1  
giflib                    5.2.1                h36c2ea0_2    conda-forge
glib                      2.72.1               h6239696_0    conda-forge
glib-tools                2.72.1               h6239696_0    conda-forge
gmp                       6.2.1                h58526e2_0    conda-forge
gnutls                    3.7.6                hf3e180e_5    conda-forge
google-auth               2.6.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0    anaconda
google-auth-oauthlib      0.4.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0    anaconda
google-pasta              0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0    anaconda
graphite2                 1.3.13            h58526e2_1001    conda-forge
grpcio                    1.42.0           py39hce63b2e_0    anaconda
gsl                       2.7                  he838d99_0    conda-forge
gst-plugins-base          1.20.3               hf6a322e_0    conda-forge
gstreamer                 1.20.3               hd4edc92_0    conda-forge
gxx_impl_linux-64         11.2.0               h1234567_1  
h5py                      2.10.0           py39hec9cf62_0    anaconda
harfbuzz                  5.1.0                hf9f4e7c_0    conda-forge
hdf5                      1.10.6          nompi_h6a2412b_1114    conda-forge
icu                       70.1                 h27087fc_0    conda-forge
idna                      3.3                pyhd3eb1b0_0    anaconda
imagecodecs-lite          2019.12.3        py39hd257fcd_5    conda-forge
imageio                   2.21.1             pyhfa7a67d_0    conda-forge
imgviz                    1.5.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
importlib-metadata        4.11.3           py39h06a4308_0    anaconda
importlib_resources       5.9.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
intel-openmp              2021.4.0          h06a4308_3561    anaconda
ipykernel                 6.15.1             pyh210e3f2_0    conda-forge
ipython                   8.4.0            py39hf3d152e_0    conda-forge
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                      py_1    conda-forge
jack                      1.9.18            h8c3723f_1002    conda-forge
jedi                      0.18.1             pyhd8ed1ab_2    conda-forge
jinja2                    3.1.2              pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
joblib                    1.1.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jpeg                      9e                   h166bdaf_2    conda-forge
json-c                    0.16                 hc379101_0    conda-forge
json5                     0.9.5              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
jsonschema                4.9.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyter_client            7.3.4              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyter_core              4.11.1           py39hf3d152e_0    conda-forge
jupyter_server            1.18.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyterlab                3.4.5              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyterlab_pygments       0.2.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyterlab_server         2.12.0           py39h06a4308_0  
keras-preprocessing       1.1.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0    anaconda
kernel-headers_linux-64   2.6.32              he073ed8_15    conda-forge
keyutils                  1.6.1                h166bdaf_0    conda-forge
kiwisolver                1.4.4            py39hf939315_0    conda-forge
krb5                      1.19.3               h3790be6_0    conda-forge
labelme                   5.0.1            py39hf3d152e_0    conda-forge
lame                      3.100             h7f98852_1001    conda-forge
lcms2                     2.12                 hddcbb42_0    conda-forge
ld_impl_linux-64          2.38                 h1181459_1  
lerc                      4.0.0                h27087fc_0    conda-forge
libblas                   3.9.0            12_linux64_mkl    conda-forge
libbrotlicommon           1.0.9                h166bdaf_7    conda-forge
libbrotlidec              1.0.9                h166bdaf_7    conda-forge
libbrotlienc              1.0.9                h166bdaf_7    conda-forge
libcap                    2.64                 ha37c62d_0    conda-forge
libcblas                  3.9.0            12_linux64_mkl    conda-forge
libclang                  14.0.6          default_h2e3cab8_0    conda-forge
libclang13                14.0.6          default_h3a83d3e_0    conda-forge
libcups                   2.3.3                hf5a7f15_1    conda-forge
libcurl                   7.83.1               h7bff187_0    conda-forge
libdb                     6.2.32               h9c3ff4c_0    conda-forge
libdeflate                1.13                 h166bdaf_0    conda-forge
libdrm                    2.4.112              h166bdaf_0    conda-forge
libedit                   3.1.20191231         he28a2e2_2    conda-forge
libev                     4.33                 h516909a_1    conda-forge
libevent                  2.1.10               h9b69904_4    conda-forge
libffi                    3.4.2                h7f98852_5    conda-forge
libflac                   1.3.4                h27087fc_0    conda-forge
libgcc-devel_linux-64     11.2.0               h1234567_1  
libgcc-ng                 12.1.0              h8d9b700_16    conda-forge
libgfortran-ng            11.2.0               h00389a5_1  
libgfortran5              11.2.0               h1234567_1  
libglib                   2.72.1               h2d90d5f_0    conda-forge
libgomp                   12.1.0              h8d9b700_16    conda-forge
libiconv                  1.16                 h516909a_0    conda-forge
libidn2                   2.3.3                h166bdaf_0    conda-forge
liblapack                 3.9.0            12_linux64_mkl    conda-forge
libllvm14                 14.0.6               he0ac6c6_0    conda-forge
libnghttp2                1.47.0               hdcd2b5c_1    conda-forge
libnsl                    2.0.0                h7f98852_0    conda-forge
libogg                    1.3.4                h7f98852_1    conda-forge
libopus                   1.3.1                h7f98852_1    conda-forge
libpciaccess              0.16                 h516909a_0    conda-forge
libpng                    1.6.37               h753d276_3    conda-forge
libpq                     14.5                 hd77ab85_0    conda-forge
libprotobuf               3.20.1               h4ff587b_0    anaconda
libsndfile                1.0.31               h9c3ff4c_1    conda-forge
libsodium                 1.0.18               h36c2ea0_1    conda-forge
libssh2                   1.10.0               haa6b8db_3    conda-forge
libstdcxx-devel_linux-64  11.2.0               h1234567_1  
libstdcxx-ng              12.1.0              ha89aaad_16    conda-forge
libtasn1                  4.18.0               h166bdaf_1    conda-forge
libtiff                   4.4.0                h0e0dad5_3    conda-forge
libtool                   2.4.6             h9c3ff4c_1008    conda-forge
libunistring              0.9.10               h7f98852_0    conda-forge
libuuid                   2.32.1            h7f98852_1000    conda-forge
libva                     2.15.0               h166bdaf_0    conda-forge
libvorbis                 1.3.7                h9c3ff4c_0    conda-forge
libvpx                    1.11.0               h9c3ff4c_3    conda-forge
libwebp                   1.2.3                h522a892_1    conda-forge
libwebp-base              1.2.3                h166bdaf_2    conda-forge
libxcb                    1.13              h7f98852_1004    conda-forge
libxkbcommon              1.0.3                he3ba5ed_0    conda-forge
libxml2                   2.9.14               h22db469_3    conda-forge
libxslt                   1.1.35               h8affb1d_0    conda-forge
libzlib                   1.2.12               h166bdaf_2    conda-forge
llvm-openmp               14.0.4               he0ac6c6_0    conda-forge
locket                    1.0.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
lxml                      4.9.1            py39hb9d737c_0    conda-forge
lz4-c                     1.9.3                h9c3ff4c_1    conda-forge
make                      4.3                  hd18ef5c_1    conda-forge
markdown                  3.3.4            py39h06a4308_0    anaconda
markupsafe                2.1.1            py39hb9d737c_1    conda-forge
matplotlib-base           3.5.2            py39h700656a_1    conda-forge
matplotlib-inline         0.1.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
mistune                   0.8.4           py39h3811e60_1005    conda-forge
mkl                       2021.4.0           h06a4308_640    anaconda
mkl-service               2.4.0            py39h7f8727e_0    anaconda
mkl_fft                   1.3.1            py39hd3c417c_0    anaconda
mkl_random                1.2.2            py39h51133e4_0    anaconda
multidict                 5.2.0            py39h7f8727e_2    anaconda
munkres                   1.1.4              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
mysql-common              8.0.30               haf5c9bc_0    conda-forge
mysql-libs                8.0.30               h28c427c_0    conda-forge
natsort                   8.1.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
nbclassic                 0.4.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
nbclient                  0.6.6              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
nbconvert                 6.5.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
nbconvert-core            6.5.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
nbconvert-pandoc          6.5.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
nbformat                  5.4.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
ncurses                   6.3                  h5eee18b_3  
nest-asyncio              1.5.5              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
nettle                    3.8.1                hc379101_1    conda-forge
networkx                  2.8.5              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
notebook                  6.4.12             pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
notebook-shim             0.1.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
nspr                      4.32                 h9c3ff4c_1    conda-forge
nss                       3.78                 h2350873_0    conda-forge
numpy                     1.22.3           py39he7a7128_0    anaconda
numpy-base                1.22.3           py39hf524024_0    anaconda
oauthlib                  3.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0    anaconda
openh264                  2.2.0                h27087fc_2    conda-forge
openjpeg                  2.4.0                hb52868f_1    conda-forge
openssl                   1.1.1q               h166bdaf_0    conda-forge
opt_einsum                3.3.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1    anaconda
p11-kit                   0.24.1               hc5aa10d_0    conda-forge
packaging                 21.3               pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pandoc                    2.19                 ha770c72_0    conda-forge
pandocfilters             1.5.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pango                     1.50.9               hc4f8a73_0    conda-forge
parso                     0.8.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
partd                     1.2.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pcre                      8.45                 h9c3ff4c_0    conda-forge
pcre2                     10.37                hc3806b6_1    conda-forge
pexpect                   4.8.0              pyh9f0ad1d_2    conda-forge
pickleshare               0.7.5                   py_1003    conda-forge
pillow                    9.2.0            py39hae2aec6_0    conda-forge
pip                       22.1.2           py39h06a4308_0  
pixman                    0.40.0               h36c2ea0_0    conda-forge
pkgutil-resolve-name      1.3.10             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
portaudio                 19.6.0               h57a0ea0_5    conda-forge
prometheus_client         0.14.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
prompt-toolkit            3.0.30             pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
protobuf                  3.20.1           py39h295c915_0    anaconda
psutil                    5.9.1            py39hb9d737c_0    conda-forge
pthread-stubs             0.4               h36c2ea0_1001    conda-forge
ptyprocess                0.7.0              pyhd3deb0d_0    conda-forge
pulseaudio                14.0                 h583eb01_5    conda-forge
pure_eval                 0.2.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyasn1                    0.4.8              pyhd3eb1b0_0    anaconda
pyasn1-modules            0.2.8                      py_0    anaconda
pycparser                 2.21               pyhd3eb1b0_0    anaconda
pyglet                    1.5.16           py39hf3d152e_1    conda-forge
pygments                  2.12.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyjwt                     2.1.0            py39h06a4308_0    anaconda
pyopenssl                 21.0.0             pyhd3eb1b0_1    anaconda
pyparsing                 3.0.9              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyrsistent                0.18.1           py39hb9d737c_1    conda-forge
pyside2                   5.15.5           py39hbfe2af7_1    conda-forge
pysocks                   1.7.1            py39h06a4308_0    anaconda
python                    3.9.13          h9a8a25e_0_cpython    conda-forge
python-dateutil           2.8.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
python-fastjsonschema     2.16.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
python-flatbuffers        2.0                pyhd3eb1b0_0    anaconda
python_abi                3.9                      2_cp39    conda-forge
pytz                      2022.2.1           pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pywavelets                1.3.0            py39hd257fcd_1    conda-forge
pyyaml                    6.0              py39hb9d737c_4    conda-forge
pyzmq                     23.2.1           py39headdf64_0    conda-forge
qt-main                   5.15.4               ha5833f6_2    conda-forge
qt-webengine              5.15.4               hcbadb6c_3    conda-forge
qtpy                      2.2.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
r-base                    4.1.3                ha8c3e7c_2    conda-forge
r-uuid                    1.1_0             r41h06615bd_0    conda-forge
readline                  8.1.2                h7f8727e_1  
requests                  2.27.1             pyhd3eb1b0_0    anaconda
requests-oauthlib         1.3.0                      py_0    anaconda
rsa                       4.7.2              pyhd3eb1b0_1    anaconda
scikit-image              0.19.3           py39h1832856_1    conda-forge
scikit-learn              1.1.1            py39h6a678d5_0  
scipy                     1.9.0            py39h8ba3f38_0    conda-forge
sed                       4.8                  he412f7d_0    conda-forge
send2trash                1.8.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
setuptools                61.2.0           py39h06a4308_0  
six                       1.16.0             pyhd3eb1b0_1    anaconda
sniffio                   1.2.0            py39hf3d152e_3    conda-forge
soupsieve                 2.3.2.post1        pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
sqlite                    3.39.2               h5082296_0  
stack_data                0.4.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
svt-av1                   1.1.0                h27087fc_1    conda-forge
sysroot_linux-64          2.12                he073ed8_15    conda-forge
tensorboard               2.4.0              pyhc547734_0    anaconda
tensorboard-plugin-wit    1.6.0                      py_0    anaconda
tensorflow                2.4.1           gpu_py39h8236f22_0    anaconda
tensorflow-base           2.4.1           gpu_py39h29c2da4_0    anaconda
tensorflow-estimator      2.6.0              pyh7b7c402_0    anaconda
tensorflow-gpu            2.4.1                h30adc30_0    anaconda
termcolor                 1.1.0            py39h06a4308_1    anaconda
terminado                 0.15.0           py39hf3d152e_0    conda-forge
threadpoolctl             3.1.0              pyh8a188c0_0    conda-forge
tifffile                  2020.6.3                   py_0    conda-forge
tinycss2                  1.1.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
tk                        8.6.12               h1ccaba5_0  
tktable                   2.10                 hb7b940f_3    conda-forge
toolz                     0.12.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
tornado                   6.2              py39hb9d737c_0    conda-forge
traitlets                 5.3.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
typing-extensions         4.1.1                hd3eb1b0_0    anaconda
typing_extensions         4.1.1              pyh06a4308_0    anaconda
tzdata                    2022a                hda174b7_0  
unicodedata2              14.0.0           py39hb9d737c_1    conda-forge
urllib3                   1.26.9           py39h06a4308_0    anaconda
wcwidth                   0.2.5              pyh9f0ad1d_2    conda-forge
webencodings              0.5.1                      py_1    conda-forge
websocket-client          1.3.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
werkzeug                  2.0.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0    anaconda
wheel                     0.37.1             pyhd3eb1b0_0  
wrapt                     1.13.3           py39h7f8727e_2    anaconda
xcb-util                  0.4.0                h166bdaf_0    conda-forge
xcb-util-image            0.4.0                h166bdaf_0    conda-forge
xcb-util-keysyms          0.4.0                h166bdaf_0    conda-forge
xcb-util-renderutil       0.3.9                h166bdaf_0    conda-forge
xcb-util-wm               0.4.1                h166bdaf_0    conda-forge
xorg-fixesproto           5.0               h7f98852_1002    conda-forge
xorg-kbproto              1.0.7             h7f98852_1002    conda-forge
xorg-libice               1.0.10               h7f98852_0    conda-forge
xorg-libsm                1.2.3             hd9c2040_1000    conda-forge
xorg-libx11               1.7.2                h7f98852_0    conda-forge
xorg-libxau               1.0.9                h7f98852_0    conda-forge
xorg-libxdmcp             1.1.3                h7f98852_0    conda-forge
xorg-libxext              1.3.4                h7f98852_1    conda-forge
xorg-libxfixes            5.0.3             h7f98852_1004    conda-forge
xorg-libxrender           0.9.10            h7f98852_1003    conda-forge
xorg-libxt                1.2.1                h7f98852_2    conda-forge
xorg-renderproto          0.11.1            h7f98852_1002    conda-forge
xorg-xextproto            7.3.0             h7f98852_1002    conda-forge
xorg-xproto               7.0.31            h7f98852_1007    conda-forge
xz                        5.2.5                h7f8727e_1  
yaml                      0.2.5                h7f98852_2    conda-forge
yarl                      1.6.3            py39h27cfd23_0    anaconda
zeromq                    4.3.4                h9c3ff4c_1    conda-forge
zipp                      3.8.0            py39h06a4308_0    anaconda
zlib                      1.2.12               h7f8727e_2  
zstd                      1.5.2                h8a70e8d_3    conda-forge
```

Comment: @André yeah, sorry

Comment: Can you add what is currently in your environment? I.e. `conda list` output

Comment: `it's not even a super complex library` <- It requires `~195` packages to be installed, though (This is the number of packages that need to be installed in a fresh env). Seeing that your env is already so crowded, it is probably not trivial to solve. Especially `conda` can sometimes get stuck. Additionally, you have a mix of channels used in your env. Might be a good idea to try and create a clean new environemnt from scratch. Think about which packages you need for your project, put them in an environment.yml file and then try to create that environment